# Let $p$ be prime. Let $S$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. If $x\in G$ then $xSx^{-1}$ is a Sylow $p$-group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, sylow-theory

Let $p$ be prime. Let $S$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. If $x\in G$ then $xSx^{-1}$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

**My attempt:**

Let $|G|=p^n\cdot m$ where $p$ is prime, $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\nmid m$ then as $S$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ we have that:

$$|S|=p^n$$

Moreover, we know that:

$$xSx^{-1}=\{xsx^{-1}\mid s\in S\}$$

Let $\phi: S \rightarrow xSx^{-1}$ such that $\phi(s) = xsx^{-1}$. Clearly $\phi$ is bijective and $\phi(s) = xsx^{-1}$

Then $S$ is isomorphic to $xSx^{-1}$ and $|S| = |xSx^{-1}|$

In consequence

$$|xSx^{-1}| = p^n$$

and $xSx^{-1}$ is a Sylow $p$-group.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You haven't shown $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: To be clear, $\phi$ *is* a homomorphism, but @Shaun is correct that you haven't *shown* that to be the case, so there's a gap in your proof.

Comment: To conclude that $|xSx^{-1}|=|S|$ is not necessary to mention (let alone prove) that $\phi$ is a homomorphism: being bijective suffices.

Comment: Rather, I'd first prove that $xSx^{-1}$ is a subgroup, which is a prerequisite of being it a Sylow $p$-subgroup.